# How do standing waves produce a note?

Tags: waves, acoustics, string, vibrations, harmonics

I just learned standing waves in class. And I know that fundamental frequency is the minimum frequency with which a standing can exist on a string. Then we talked about the role of standing wave in music.

**I don't very understand how do standing waves produce a note, since there is no net energy transfer through the wave. Also, what are the roles of different harmonics in the music?** Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

The standing wave on the string creates a travelling pressure wave in the air around the string, i.e. sound. (In a real musical instrument, the mechanism of sound production is a little different, but the concept remains the same. See @Hilmar 's comment on this answer.) This carries away energy and damps the oscillation on the string. Hence, the standing wave will decay; to maintain the standing wave on the string, you must drive the oscillation, through a method like pulling a bow across the string or repeatedly plucking the string.

The principle of superposition tells us that if two waves $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are allowed on the string (satisfies boundary conditions), any linear combination of them $c_1\psi_1+c_2\psi_2$ will also be allowed on the string. So, in real life, the standing wave on a string can be decomposed as a harmonic series, i.e. it is a linear combination of the pure harmonics. Typically, the fundamental frequency determines the pitch, and the smaller contributions at higher harmonics determine the timbre (tone quality).

Comment: The sound radiation by the string itself is often negligible. That’s why most musical instruments have bodies that do the actual radiation. The body is a mechanical transformer: it has a much larger surface area than the string itself. The damping comes mostly from the load that the body presents to the sting and partially from losses in the string itself.

Comment: @Hilmar Thanks for pointing that out! I've edited my answer to mention this.

Comment: Re, "what are the roles of different harmonics in the music?" That question goes deep, and it goes deep in two different directions; In human physiology, the harmonic content of a "note" underlies its _timbre._ Timbre is the musicians name for how we can tell, just by hearing it, whether the note was played on a trumpet, played on a flute, on a violin, etc. The other direction is music theory, in which harmonics underlie the structure of musical scales and musical chords. Whichever way you go though, the question probably is off-topic for a physics forum.